# Typescript: Custom interface type using enum

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, types, enums

I am working with categories with my API endpoint and so I have created this `enum` for it :

```js
export enum categories {
  DESIGN = 'design',
  ART = 'art',
  WRITING = 'writing',
  PHOTOGRAPHY = 'photography',
  MUSIC = 'music',
  DIGITAL = 'digital',
  MEDIA = 'media'
}
```

And now I want to use this to set an interface for the `category` attribute in my database.

> `interface` for that :

```js
interface ProjectAttrs {
  user: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  category:   // <== I want it to be either of those values defined above
}
```

How do I specify the category interface type to be either of the values defined in the enum?

Comment: Try `category: categories` and if that doesn't work for you, try to post a [mcve] that shows what goes wrong and what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

Just put the enum name `categories` like this:

```
interface ProjectAttrs {
  user: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  category: categories;
}
```

Here is a working [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-bx9cuj)